# T4 conditionally including templates

Tags: .net, t4

I am creating a T4 template that I wish to conditionally include templates based on some criteria.  For example I have tried the following...

```
<#switch(iocContainer) {#>
<#case "Autofac":#>
    <#@ include file="Autofac\EntityTemplate.ttinclude" #>
    <#@ include file="Autofac\ServiceTemplate.ttinclude" #>
    <#@ include file="Autofac\RepositoryTemplate.ttinclude" #>
    <#@ include file="Autofac\DbContextTemplate.ttinclude" #>
<#break;#>

<#case "Castle":#>
    <#@ include file="Castle\EntityTemplate.ttinclude" #>
    <#@ include file="Castle\ServiceTemplate.ttinclude" #>
    <#@ include file="Castle\RepositoryTemplate.ttinclude" #>
    <#@ include file="Castle\DbContextTemplate.ttinclude" #>
<#break;#>

<#case "nInject":#>
    <#@ include file="nInject\EntityTemplate.ttinclude" #>
    <#@ include file="nInject\ServiceTemplate.ttinclude" #>
    <#@ include file="nInject\RepositoryTemplate.ttinclude" #>
    <#@ include file="nInject\DbContextTemplate.ttinclude" #>
<#break;
}#>
```

The problem is when the templating engine runs, it appears to preprocess all the includes before evaluating any code.  So the switch statement above isn't running and T4 attempts to include all the files.

Is there a way to conditionally include T4 templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, T4 doesn't include conditional includes by design. The directives will all be processed.

If you invert your logic you can solve this. Split the T4 content above and below your switch statement into two separate files (let's call them `start.ttinclude` and `end.ttinclude`). Then create three separate T4 templates called, say, `autofac.tt`, `castle.tt` and `ninject.tt`. These would each looks something like this (this is `castle.tt`):

```
<#@ include file="start.ttinclude" #>
<#@ include file="Castle\EntityTemplate.ttinclude" #>
<#@ include file="Castle\ServiceTemplate.ttinclude" #>
<#@ include file="Castle\RepositoryTemplate.ttinclude" #>
<#@ include file="Castle\DbContextTemplate.ttinclude" #>
<#@ include file="end.ttinclude" #>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, place the content of the template inside an #IF #ENDIF block and use #DEFINEs to cause the content to be skipped even though the file itself is included.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind running within a Visual Studio container, then DTE can help you out here.

```
<#@ template hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Data" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Xml.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ Import namespace="System.Linq"                    #>
<#@ Import namespace="System.Reflection"              #>
<#@ Import namespace="System.Linq.Expressions"        #>
<#@ Import namespace="System.Collections.Generic"     #>
<#@ Import namespace="System.Linq"                    #>
<#@ Import namespace="System.Text"                    #>
<# 
    if(isDefined("spike2" , "TTs")) {
        WriteLine("//the constant TTs is defined");
    }
    else
    {
        WriteLine("//the constant TTs is not defined");
    }
#>
<#+
        private bool isDefined(string projectName, string constantToCheck){
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)this.Host;
            DTE dte = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;  

            try
            {   
                // find a project called "Spike2"
                Project prj = (from p in getProjects(dte) where p.Name.ToLower() == projectName.ToLower() select p).FirstOrDefault(); 

                // get its active configuration
                var config = prj.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration;


                var defineConstants = (from p in getConfigProperties(config) where p.Name == "DefineConstants" select p.Value).FirstOrDefault().ToString(); 
                var constants = defineConstants.Split(';');
                return Array.Exists(constants, define => define == constantToCheck);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Write(ex.Message);
            }
            return false;
        }

        static private IEnumerable<Property> getConfigProperties(Configuration config) {
            for(int i=1; i <=  config.Properties.Count; i++)
            {
                yield return  config.Properties.Item(i);
            }
        }

        static private IEnumerable<Project> getProjects(DTE dte) {
            for(int i=1; i <= dte.Solution.Projects.Count; i++)
            {
                yield return dte.Solution.Projects.Item(i);
            }
        }
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to include a different config file per developer machine and also to have a default app.config.  This will only work when you don't want processing for the "included" files.

File name App.tt.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ output extension=".config" #>
<#
string pathToConfigurations = Host.ResolvePath("Configurations");
string pathToMachine = Path.Combine(pathToConfigurations, Environment.MachineName + ".config");
if (File.Exists(pathToMachine))
{
    Write(File.ReadAllText(pathToMachine)); 
}
else
{
    Write(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(pathToConfigurations, "App.config")));  
}
#>
```